# Jelastic connection to MongoDB Not working On Remote tomcat but ok when Local tomcat connect to remote Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, authentication, jelastic

I have an environment on Jelastic, their support wasn't able to help :P

I setup Tomcat 7.0.55 with java 8 and MongoDB 2.6.4
For mongo i also setup an external ip so i can access from my local tomcat.

Here what happen,
I am able to run my local Tomcat and Jelastic remote Mongo DB
But when deployed, i get this log from the remote mongo

```
2015-01-07T22:57:29.637+0000 [conn22208]  authenticate db: easylend {authenticate: 1, user: "cre8tech", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-01-07T22:57:29.638+0000 [conn22208] Failed to authenticate cre8tech@easylend with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed keymismatch
```

I am 1000% sure that the credential is correct and so the method use to log because i am able to use it locally to their remote mongo + i can access to it by using

> mongo XXXX.whelastic.net/{myDbName} --username {username} --password {password}

```
@Bean
@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    ServerAddress serverAdress = new ServerAddress(host, Integer.parseInt(port));  
    Mongo mongo = null;
    if (usr != null && !usr.isEmpty()) {
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(usr, database, pwd.toCharArray());
        mongo = new MongoClient(serverAdress, Arrays.asList(credential));

    } else {
        mongo = new MongoClient(serverAdress);
    }

    mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);

    return mongo;
}
```

The log on tomcat just says that it cannot be authenticated

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "********" , "code" : 18 , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth fails"}
```

My theory is that the remote Jelastic tomcat may contains some jar/libs that interfere with the mongo driver I use

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

no need to search any longer
I found the issue

The tomcat on Jelastic inherit from some linux command such as pwd which is use to show the current directory
I use pwd in my property to retrieve the password.
It shouldn't collide but it does and i am getting /opt/tomcat as password instead of my password

It may be something you will need to fix in your end so these variable doesn't get mix with a file properties

The work around is to have a different  property name

The same apply for Amazon beanstalk

Thanks